# Compass is not pointing to spawnpoint in 1.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

In my survival world in Minecraft, I built a compass. It *was* working fine, but when the 1.9 update arrived it started acting haywire! It doesn't point to my spawn point OR my bed. When I followed it to where it was pointing, I ended up in the middle of nowhere. (I know it wasn't my spawn point because my spawn point was next to a mushroom tree and I built a house around it.)

I used my compass a lot! Why doesn't it work anymore?

No mods are being used, not on a server, just a regular vanilla single player world.

Comment: Have you tried making another one?  It's possible it's a bug.

Comment: Could you back up your world, break your bed, die and check where you respawn? It may be that your spawnpoint has moved.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try them. I prefer not to die though, I am playing Survival mode!  =)

Comment: I have experienced this problem in my 1.9 world, including maps. (my cursor isn't in the right place) When I relog, everything goes back to normal. Does this happen to you? Try relogging and see what happens. It could be a bug.

Comment: There are some things you could check:

    Other worlds. Mark your bed and spawn somehow, then get lost with a compass.

    Coordinates. In the compass middle-point, what are the coords? Are they somehow usefull (zero coord lines intersection, old spawn point, … )?

    Does the compass needle change direction after you sleep? Or after you die (/gamerule keepInventory true for safety before dieing)? Or maybe after you move your bed? Do you spawn at a different place after dieing?

    Did this happen to anybody else? A friend, some bloke guy on Google? //part 1

Comment: //part 2: 
If you answered always no to youself, go shoot yourself use coordinates instead of compasses (see coords after pressing F3) - remember your base X and Z values.